# How to store/query users meta-data by zip code

Tags: mysql, latitude-longitude, zipcode, bigdata

I have a complicated issue but rather than go into the specifics i have simplified it to the following.

Lets say we are trying to build a system, where users of the system can apply for priority levels on various services on a per zip-code basis.  This system would have four tables like so...

```
CREATE TABLE `zip_code` (
  `zip` varchar(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `lat` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `long` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
  PRIMARY KEY (`zip`,`lat`,`long`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `user_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `service` (
  `service_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `service_priority` (
  `user_id` int(10) NOT NULL',
  `service_id` int(10) NOT NULL',
  `zip` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `priority` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Now lets also say that we have 45000 zip-codes, a few hundred services and a few thousand users, and that no user can have the same priority level as another user for the same service in the same zip code.

I need a query that if given a particular zip code, radius, service, and a user_id will return the highest available priority level for all other zip codes within that radius for that service.

And, also, would like to know any suggestions for restructuring this data.

The problem that i see happening here is as the user base grows, the service_priority table is going to get huge,  in theory 45000 rows bigger for every user although in practice probably only 10000 rows bigger.

What can i do to mitigate these problems?

Comment: Zip codes don't have a single lat/long, they're polygons, so I'm not sure how this is going to work. You'll probably want to look into getting a 3rd party database of zip code info. You'll also want to use spatial types rather than floats. There's [MySQL's spatial extensions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-extensions.html), or better, [PostgreSQL's GIS extension](http://postgis.net/). Or look into using a 3rd party for any location services.

Comment: It sounds like you are using a simple-minded centroid for each zip?  45K sounds like US zipcodes; `VARCHAR(7)` sounds like a mistake -- should be `CHAR(5)`?  Or `MEDIUMINT(5) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL`.

Comment: Both of these comments sound correct to me.  We are in fact just using the centerpoint of the zipcode and therefore our system will not be very accurate as to real zip borders.  Also, it is just US zips for now but our DB also has Canadian zips which are alphanumeric.  In theory we may someday do business in Canada.  just learning of the spatial extensions now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to InnoDB.

`zip_code` table should probably have `PRIMARY KEY(zip)` unless you really want multiple rows for a given zip.

"no user can have the same priority level as another user for the same service in the same zip code" -- can be enforced by

```
service_priority : UNIQUE(service_id, user_id, zip)
```

Then your query may look something like

```
SELECT sp.*
    FROM ( SELECT b.zip
             FROM ( SELECT lat, lng FROM zip_code WHERE zip = '$zip' ) AS a
             JOIN zip_code AS b
             WHERE ... < $radius
         ) AS z
    JOIN service_priority AS sp
    WHERE sp.zip = z.zip
      AND sp.user_id = $user_id
      AND sp.service_id = $service_id
    ORDER BY sp.priority DESC
    LIMIT 1
```

Notes:

- The index, above, is also tailored for this query.
- The innermost query gets the one lat/lng for the center point.
- The middle query focuses on finding the nearby zips.  See the tag I added to find many questions discussion how to do that.
- The outer query then filters results based on user and service.
- Finally, the highest priority row is picked.